# Corona Enterprise Xcode proj runs in simulator, but fails to archive "app_sign cannot resign <myapp>"

Tags: xcode, coronasdk, signing

I'm at the point where I'm ready to build, but when I try to archive the project I get the following error in xcode:

> app_sign cannot resign
>   /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-App-bzgdaitstcabzpaiygqfnluetfhk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/My-App.app/My
>   App. Please remove and then build

Does anyone know why this is happening?

In build settings I've tried leaving the code signing identity blank, and tried it with the correct distribution profile.
I've tried with and without the provisioning profile specified. 
I've tried deleting the whole file in my DerivedData folder.

It would seem that this is the line in question that causes the problem:

> "$TOOL_PATH" app_sign sign "$SHARED_RESOURCE_DIR/developerkey.cert"
>   "$CORONA_RESOURCE_CAR_PATH/resource.car" "$CORONA_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
>   little

But I don't know enough about what it's doing here to think of the solution. If I build the sample app that comes with Corona Enterprise still builds fine, but my own app still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was to do with the xcode.proj file itself. Not sure what the cause was, it seemed to be keeping a reference to a file which no longer existed, rather than the new build. 
I made a new project, copied all of my own source files across but left the new proj files in, and then it built successfully.